# How to force a pty.spawn() launched application to cleanly exit?

Tags: python, pty

I'm developing a simple service that binds to a port and spawns a pty for an application, `dup()`ing `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` to the socket, so that the socket takes control over the `pty`:

```
prevOutFd = os.dup(1)
prevInFd = os.dup(0)
prevErrFd = os.dup(2)
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    logging.info('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    # redirect stdout, stdin and stderr to socket fd
    os.dup2(conn.fileno(),0)
    os.dup2(conn.fileno(),1)
    os.dup2(conn.fileno(),2)
    p=pty.spawn("/usr/sbin/pppd")
    # redirect stdout, stdin and stderr back to original fds
    os.dup2(prevOutFd, 0)
    os.dup2(prevInFd, 1)
    os.dup2(prevErrFd, 2)
    logging.info("Closing connection....")
    conn.close()
```

This works just fine, except for when the client abruptly kills the connection.
The server handles it just fine, but the spawned application is left defunct in the system:

`root      9820  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   16:19   0:00 [pppd] <defunct>`

I believe the solution is to either wait for the application to finish OR cleanly shut it down.
However, `pty` does not seem to have a `close()` method of some sort.

Anyone know how to cleanly shut a `pty.spawn()`ed application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [*wait()*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) the exited process like this:

```
pty.spawn("cmd")    # it returns nothing
os.wait()
```

You can also set a SIGCHLD handler so exited child processes can be automatically *wait*ed.

```
def sig_child(signum, bt):
    os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)

signal.signal(SIGCHLD, sig_child)

pty.spawn("cmd")
```